# google app script gmail testing

Tags: testing, google-apps-script, gmail-api

I want to make a clean up script for Gmail to my needs. I happy to use a script, which code I found in a blog, but now I need to modify it.

How can I test it without risking my Gmail box? I'm not good or experienced inJS, so I'm pretty sure there will be some mistakes. And I don't want my emails messed up. Is there a sandbox, or some kind of testing environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. You should create a test account for you to work with.

Also, when working with your account. You could always just log an action instead of doing it. i.e. instead of

`thread.moveToTrash()`

do a

`Logger.log('move thread "'+thread.getFirstMessageSubject()+'" to trash');`

Then check menu View > Logs to verify the actions your script would do. You could also create a `TEST` variable and use it as condition in your code to determine if it should perform an action or just log it (or both).

Comment: Thank you, will use these tricks!

Btw, doesn't Google rules forbid a person to create second account?

Comment: Really?? That's weird.. well, maybe it makes sense for Google+ accounts. But a Gmail account for developing and testing purposes, hum... I'll research.

Comment: I've just read Google's [Term of Service](https://www.google.com.br/intl/en/policies/terms/regional.html), there's nothing about this there.

Comment: I wasn't sure. It's a surprise for me that Google allows several accounts. Thank you!